# How can I add border radius and drop shadow for IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Is there anyway to do this for IE8?

```
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #585858; /* FF3.5+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #585858; /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #585858; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9 */

    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/). It adds rounded corners, drop-shadow and gradient background support for IE.

Hope this helps !

Comment: +1 for CSS3Pie -- a spectacularly good product; blows all the other solutions out of the water. It basically gives CSS-based rounded corners and drop shadows to all versions of IE (even IE6).

Answer (score 3):

For shadow on IE8 you can use

```
.box-shadow {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4,Direction=135,Color='#000000')";
}
```

where `Strength` is the density of the shadow and `Direction` is the angle of the shadow's offset in 45 degrees increments. See [Direction Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532866%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is not compatible with either drop shadows or rounded corners.

Drop shadows and rounded corners are usually best done with png images, then hacked for IE6.

Alternatively you could use something like spiffy corners (http://www.spiffycorners.com/) for rounded corners.